# how to update notification with system battery status in android

Tags: android

In notification i try to update my battery status. I create notification with service. But i don't know how to update Notofication with battery status:

I also read this docs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

MainActivity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
..
}


private BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        private int scale = -1;
        private int level = -1;
        private int voltage = -1;
        private int temp = -1;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
            voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);

            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(ns);
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            String percent = ((level * 100) / scale) + "%";
            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.call, percent, when);
            /* <set your intents here> */
            mNotificationManager.notify(7331, notification);

            Log.d(TAG, "Battery level is " + level + "/" + scale + ", temp is " + temp + ", voltage is " + voltage);
        }
    };
```

and i am using service which create Notification like

```
private void showNotification() {
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.call, getString(R.string.notification_text), System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notification_label), getString(R.string.notification_text_short), pi);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground(7331, notification);
    }
```

error:

```
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } in com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity$1@41558b80
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:737)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentView required: pkg=com.xxx.xxx id=7331 notification=Notification(contentView=null vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x0)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at 
android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:317)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:127)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:106)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:72)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
12-07 14:46:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(25758):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: I think you did not set your contentView in onCreate() method for your activity.

Comment: Previous commenter is correct; every notification needs a contentView. Use the Notification.Builder class (available in API 11, or in the support-v4 library for earlier platforms) to generate your notification object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to *use permission* BATTERY_STATS.
and if you want to update notification, you have to use PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT as flag in PendingActivity.getActivity

here's some code from my app :

```
final NotificationManager notificationMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
note.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
note.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

Intent intent = null;
PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;

intent = new Intent(context, MailActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

note.setLatestEventInfo(context, "nyxdroid", text, pendingIntent);
notificationMgr.notify(1980 + type, note);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can i instead of icon (R.drawable.icon) show text too? like 59% and battery icon?